# how to insert values from multiple rows into a record in oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, insert-into

I have a table A like this:

```
   id   field      value
----------------------
   1845  name       john
   1845  post       manager
   1845  birth      1980
   1846  name       alex
   1846  post       employee
   1846  birth      1986
```

i want a result set that look like this:

```
     id     name     post     birth
----------------------------------------
    1845    john    manager   1980
    1846    alex    employee  1986
.
.
.
```

is there any way in oracle to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that ID field will have the same number for a given name, post and birth, the following query might help you.

```
select 
  distinct 
  id,
  (select value from test where id = a.id and field = 'name') as name,
  (select value from test where id = a.id and field = 'post') as post,
  (select value from test where id = a.id and field = 'birth') as birth
from test a
```

Note that the above query will **not** work for the case below where there are 2 names for the same ID:

```
id   field      value
----------------------
1845  name       john
1845  post       manager
1845  birth      1980
1845  name       alex
1845  post       employee
1845  birth      1986
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca93f/3